# How to create a dataframe by using column names and text/excel files using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a text/excel files in by blob storage, and I want to fecth only certain columns from that files and create a dataframe.

for ex:
a,b,c,d,e are the columns present in my file
I have the path for that file :/mnt/reservoir/files/file1.txt

I want to create a dataframe by using this file and fetching only columns b,c,d

how to achieve this using pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

To work around this and create a dataframe using specific columns we have to create another data frame after reading the whole text/excel file.

***Code Example:***

```py
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimter", ",").load("/mnt/reservoir/files/file1.txt")

df2 = df.select(df.b, df.c, df.d)

OR

df3 = df.select(df.columns[1:4])
```

**My sample file reading**

[image]

**Output**

[image]